# Javascript logic/behaviour error

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a overlay on the images of a website when you hover them. I implemented this here and it's working fine  http://jsfiddle.net/stujLbjh/

This is the js code:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.image-thumb');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) 
{
    var overlay = document.createElement('a')
    overlay.className = 'icon-overlay';
    overlay.href = '#';

    divs[i].appendChild(overlay);

    divs[i].onmouseover = function () {
        this.querySelector('.icon-overlay').style.display = 'block';}
    divs[i].onmouseout = function () {
        this.querySelector('.icon-overlay').style.display = 'none';}
    overlay.onclick = function()  {
        alert("clicked");}
}
```

Further on, i wanted to get rid of those div declarations in html that are including the imgs and add them dynamically straight from  javascript, in order to have the same result as in the first jsfiddle, but the behaviour is weird and i miss something. You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwrae91p/1/

Any hints?

Zack.

Comment: "the behaviour is weird" — Define "weird"

Comment: If it in the first example, at hover the icon appears for every image, in the second example when i try to dynamically add the divs, if i hover the third image, the icon appears on the second and if i hover over the first image nothing happens. I've added a border for the .image-thumb class and only the second and third picture have it, and the picture is overlapping a empty div.

Comment: Check your browser console: _Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent._

Comment: And also: _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null_

Comment: And your code is trying to place all the images within a div.

Comment: I've posted an answer that might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `getElementsByTagName()` when trying to retrieve the images. This method is a Live NodeList, so any changes to the DOM will reflect immediately.

Like in your first code attempt, you could just use `querySelectorAll()`.

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.className = 'image-thumb';

    var overlay = document.createElement('a')
    overlay.className = 'icon-overlay';
    overlay.href = '#';

    div.appendChild(imgs[i]);
    div.appendChild(overlay);
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    div.onmouseover = function () {
        this.querySelector('.icon-overlay').style.display = 'block';
    }
    div.onmouseout = function () {
        this.querySelector('.icon-overlay').style.display = 'none';
    }
    overlay.onclick = function () {
        alert("clicked");
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/stujLbjh/3/)

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

[document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: I've learned a couple of things today. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Comment: do you have any idea why the formatting is changed when the js code is called? In the jsfiddle everything works as a charm, but if  i create a html with 3 pictures, when the page is loaded, the pictures are displayed horizontally and after the js code is called they are displayed vertically and i can't understand why because if i inject this js code, it ruins the page image formatting.

Comment: It's hard to suggest without seeing the page, but this `script` is moving the images to the `document`, and maybe they should sit in a different element. Is this the case?

Comment: In this jsFiddle, I'm placing the images back to their `parent element`, instead of the `document.body`: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/stujLbjh/8/

Comment: Take a look at this video. After the script is loaded, it messes up the arranging  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2WkcZTrJHo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Is there any chance you can publish this particular page somewhere I can see it running? So I could debug it.

Comment: There you go: https://www.sendspace.com/file/hepecv I uploaded 2 html, one created by me with 3 pictures, and one from the website to see the behavior. Thank you..

Comment: Some images are contained into links, and some are not. Do you want to keep these links?

Comment: Yes.. i want the website to be intact, to have the exact same behavior as before injecting this js code.

Comment: The problem is, these images contained into links, will have a link within another link, because you want to add the icon overlay. It would be something like: `original link -> injected div -> img -> injected link`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but i think that's the case only for the second html. In the first html, the one with only 3 pictures, doesn't have any links, only the 3 img tags and they are still rearranging after the script is called. You've helped more than enough, thank you very much!

Comment: Right... To keep the images inline, I've changed a few bits. Check the comments in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/oz5t0p19/ You'll need to adjust a bit your CSS, but that's the idea to go from.

Answer (score 1):

- You are creating **`div` element** outside the loop. That means it is
  created only one time. You need it multiple times. So **`put it inside the for loop`**.
- Use **`querySelectorAll()`** instead of **`getElementsByTagName()`**.

That's it. All of your code is perfect -- other than these two points.

Comment: @ZackKaytranada My pleasure...I am here to answer.